# WiDi not working after system formatting

Tags: windows, drivers

I have a `LG U560-G.BG51P1` notebook, which has `Intel WiDi` support. After formatting it (**Win8**), and installing all drivers and software from the manufacturer's page, I haven't managed to make WiDi work again.

The help pages says that in order for it to work, I need to have a WiDi driver and software, Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) driver and software, and CPU/WLAN WiDi enabled.

Everything is setup ok, but when I start the WiDi software, it shows me an **Incompatible Hardware** message.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which manufacturer, Intel or LG? Make sure you have latest drivers from Intel. Did you upgrade to Win 8.1?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the laptop's manufacturer? And yes, I've upgraded to 8.1 afterwards, but I firstly got this issue on W8

Comment: Have you tried drivers from both Intel and LG? Are you still receiving the same message on Windows 8.1 and have you tried updating in Device Manager?

Comment: Drivers for WiDi or Lan? Yes, I've tried either the driver provided by Intel and the one provided by LG, and I've got the same message either way

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure if you have tried the workaround listed here:
[Enabling Wireless Display (WiDi) on Windows 8 Consumer Preview](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/05/29/enabling-wireless-display-widi-on-windows-8-consumer-preview-2)

As of May 29, 2012:
*Chances are that if you have upgraded your Wireless Display (WiDi) capable laptop or tablet (with the specs mentioned here) from Windows 7 to Windows 8 Consumer Preview, then you probably stopped being able to enjoy WiDi.
The official support for WiDi on Windows 8 will come with the Intel WiDi software v3.5, and the Intel WiFi driver v15.5.*

In a nutshell, it`s a long-winded workaround that is not supported but it may work for you.

Good luck!